# Is there any way to post just TEXT on facebook friend wall , not a link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, posting, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm facing a problem while i want to post just text-msg to FB friend wall. I know that i can share link and than additionally write the msg of the post. But i am wondering if there is any way automatically to pass the msg field as a param to the dialog.
I want my text to be shown on the place of the hint "Write something..."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible and not allowed. Check out the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy):

> 2.3: Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Comment: I guess there is no way around , some hack or something ?

Comment: it´s not allowed. that is pretty much all you need to know. we are honest and serious developers here, we don´t "hack" ;)